# How to bundle a .wav sound into a Winform application .exe executable?

Tags: winforms

I have a alarm clock Winform program with a .wav sound. I would like to bundle the sound file into the exe file so that it is easier to distribute. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could include the .wav file as an [embedded resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2c9s1d7.aspx).  This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=VS.85).aspx) describes how you can play the .wav file that is embedded.